# Can we change sectionindextitlesfortableview(A To Z Alphabet) y position programmatically?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

Here I am displaying Activity List city wise , so in right side of tableview A To Z letter display in tableview but I want to change y position of A To Z letter (SectionIndexTitle).I have used following 2 delegate method of UITableview.

1) sectionIndexTitles
2) sectionForSectionIndexTitle

is it possible in iPhone? Does anyone has done similar or anyone has any suggestion please suggest.

Thanks

Comment: Are you using sectional tableview?

Comment: yes I am using sectional tableview

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible if you are using 'titleForSection' method. If you want to customise frame and other attributes you can go for 'viewForHeaderInSection'.